# Managing HTTPS Signed Cert on IIS in Express for Prod

Tags: node.js, angular, api, express, iis

How do I manage API (HTTPS) certs in DEV vs PROD in express on a node/ angular environment deployed to Windows IIS? I've seen proxy rewrites mentioned on this but I'm not sure how it is managed on express side.

I know in PROD, IIS and rewrites in web.config help manage cert for front end, but most of the tutorials I see for https on express require hard coding a self signed cert and including it in build. In PROD I have an official signed cert on server that I will use on port 8443 and not sure how that changes code, see below:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const https = require('https')
const fs = require('fs')
const port = process.env.PORT || 8443;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
res.send("IT'S WORKING!")
})

const httpsOptions = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('./security/cert.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./security/cert.pem')
}
const server = https.createServer(httpsOptions, app)
    .listen(port, () => {
    console.log('server running at ' + port)
 })
```

On a separate, but related note, how does my API service in Angular change to call the backend API for Dev vs PROD. I'm guessing something like this which IIS would re-route to PROD domain?

```
private API_URL: string = 'https://localhost:8443/api/';
```

Comment: IIS express support both client certificate and URL rewrite. So I think you could bind certificate like IIS. But you also need to bind certificate via netsh http add sslcert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've seen proxy rewrites mentioned on this but I'm not sure how it is
>   managed on express side.

It does not need managed on express side. Express does not need to know about the certs that IIS injects.

> In PROD I have an official signed cert on server that I will use on
>   port 8443 and not sure how that changes code

Express does not need cert in prod, IIS bindings handle that. So in server.js code only include httpsOptions if on dev and inserting self signed cert.

> On a separate, but related note, how does my API service in Angular
>   change to call the backend API for Dev vs PROD. I'm guessing something
>   like this which IIS would re-route to PROD domain?

Angular CLI should provide you an environments folder with environment.prod.ts and environment.ts files which will swap the variable values they hold based on build type. Simply add a variable in both for different urls for express to call when sending requests. Your prod url will not be localhost and instead should be the actual url the user will access in production.